# Get string from string using special characters

Tags: bash, unix

I have a string that looks like this:

```
p1=test: post=cxcxc,id= 895462103211,name="fdfskcksks"
```

I want to get the value  `895462103211` (the value after the expression `id=`) on variable from this string `p1`.

I need your help to get this value and thanks for your support.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On python:**

```
s = 'p1=test: post=cxcxc,id= 895462103211,name="fdfskcksks"'
res_str = s.split('id= ')[1].split(',')[0].strip()
```

**On bash:**

```
STRING='p1=test: post=cxcxc,id= 895462103211,name="fdfskcksks"'
echo $STRING | awk -F 'id= ' '{print $2}' | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'
```

Hope this was useful ;)
(languages ok?)

*Edit: formatting*
*Edit: position of id is not constant*

Comment: the postion of id isn't always the postion 2

Comment: Just change the flags, let me edit in a second

Comment: Now you first get the portion after 'id= ' and then the chars before the ','

Comment: i tried this code but  it gives error         STRING='p1=test: post=cxcxc,fdfdfdfd=hhhhh,id= 895462103211,name="fdfskcksks"'
IDCONTENT="_N"
IDCONTENT= $STRING | awk -F 'id= ' '{print $2}' | awk -F ',' '{print $1}'
echo $IDCONTENT

Comment: Use `IDCONTENT="$(echo $STRING | awk -F 'id= ' '{print $2}' | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')"`